# How to create react tab navbar links with fragment identifiers (hash links)?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, tabnavigator, react-tabs, react-router-hash-link

I have created a page with some tabs on it. Tab codes are these:

```
const [ toggleState, setToggleState ] = useState(1);

const toggleTab = (index) => {
 setToggleState(index);
}

<div className="tab-title-Container">
 <li className= {toggleState === 1 ? "tab-name active-name" : "tab-name"} 
  onClick={() => toggleTab(1)}>Tab1</li>
 <li className= {toggleState === 2 ? "tab-name active-name" : "tab-name"} 
  onClick={() => toggleTab(2)}>Tab2</li>
</div>
<div className="tab-content-Container">
 <div className= {toggleState === 1 ? "tab-content active-content" : "tab-content"}>
  Tab1 Content</div>
 <div className= {toggleState === 2 ? "tab-content active-content" : "tab-content"}>
  Tab2 Content</div>
</div>

style:
.tab-content {display: none;}
.active-content {display: block;}
```

Now I want to create navbar links of each tab. When I click Tab2 navbar link, this page should open and Tab2 switch to active class (default active tab is Tab1). I am using react-router-dom": "^6.3.0".

I need to create routes like this "https://example.com/page=01#tab1", "https://example.com/page=01#tab2" for them.

Answer (score 1):

`react-router-hash-link` AFAIK hasn't been updated to be compatible with `react-router-dom@6`. That said, it doesn't appear you are using the hash for normal purposes. The URL `hash` value can be read from the `location` object and parsed to extract the numerical tab value. Use a `useEffect` hook to "listen" for changes to the `hash` to update the local `toggleState` state.

Example:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Page = () => {
  const { hash } = useLocation();

  const [toggleState, setToggleState] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    setToggleState(Number(hash.slice(4))); // hash is "#tabX" so strip first 4 chars
  }, [hash]);

  const toggleTab = (index) => {
    setToggleState(index);
  };

  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

...

```
<Link to="/1#tab1">Page 1 tab 1</Link>
<Link to="/1#tab2">Page 1 tab 2</Link>
<Link to="/2#tab1">Page 2 tab 1</Link>
<Link to="/2#tab2">Page 2 tab 2</Link>
```

[image: Edit how-to-create-react-tab-navbar-links-with-fragment-identifiers-hash-links]

Like I said, this is a bit of an odd use of the URL hash. I think a query parameter would be an improved alternative.

Example:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Page = () => {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const { pageId } = useParams();

  const [toggleState, setToggleState] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    // access tab query parameter
    const tab = searchParams.get("tab");
    if (tab) {
      // synchronize local state
      setToggleState(Number(tab));
    } else {
      // redirect to correct tab
      searchParams.set("tab", 1);
      setSearchParams(searchParams, { replace: true });
    }
  }, [searchParams, setSearchParams]);

  const toggleTab = (index) => {
    setToggleState(index);
  };

  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

...

```
<Link to="/1?tab=1">Page 1 tab 1</Link>
<Link to="/1?tab=2">Page 1 tab 2</Link>
<Link to="/2?tab=1">Page 2 tab 1</Link>
<Link to="/2?tab=2">Page 2 tab 2</Link>
```

[image: Edit how-to-create-react-tab-navbar-links-with-fragment-identifiers-hash-links (forked)]

Comment: I tried your second solution with query parameter and it worked perfectly as desired after some customization.

Comment: One issue noticed now: If I visit directly on Page1 using <Link to="/1">Page 1</Link> all tabs show inactive. By default Tab1 should display on visiting to page. Please resolve this problem

Comment: @KulbhushanSharma Sure, it's trivial to manually redirect to a "default" tab. I've updated my answer and linked sandbox. Please do take a look when you can.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable efforts. Now its working. Is there anyway to keep our url "www.myweb.com/1" instead of "www.myweb.com/1?tab=1" only when we use <Link to="/1">Page 1</Link>?

Comment: @KulbhushanSharma Absolutely there is. I think you can just call `setToggleState(1);` in the else branch instead of updating the query search params.